When should I use proximity rule in English grammar, and how to use pronouns?
For example, we have a sentence

Mother beat her daughter because she was drunk.

who was drunk in this sentence, mother or daughter? Is the sentence ambiguous, so I can't conclude who was drunk, or should I use the proximity rule, and conclude that daughter was drunk because she is closest to the word "drunk"? I am now confused about ambiguous pronouns and proximity rule. Maybe both are valid, but I don't understand how to use them?

This question is similar to: How are pronoun ambiguities resolved? and  How to get rid of pronoun ambiguity?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

... The first duplicate even has 'We gave the bananas to the monkeys because they were here' as an example.

I left a possibly self-indulgent answer on the duplicate question making the point that apparent ambiguities are usually resolved by contextual meaning, and this is far more powerful than syntactic proximity.

As it stands, the sentence is ambiguous. Even the proximity rule cannot help much, as both interpretations are plausible. In the proper context, you might be able to disambiguate. Otherwise, it is better to change the structure of the sentence:

If the mother is drunk:


Being drunk, the mother beat her daughter.


If the daughter is drunk:


The mother beat her daughter who was drunk


In some contexts a writer may clarify by adding (the daughter) after 'she'. But I agree that it's better to re-word the sentence.
